# How can I load an MP3 or similar music file for display and analysis in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, python, mp3, wxwidgets, analysis

I'm developing a GUI in wxPython which allows a user to generate sequences of colours for some toys I'm building. Part of the program needs to load an MP3 (and potentially other formats further down the line) and display it to the user. That should be sufficient to get started but later I'd like to add features like identifying beats and some crude frequency analysis.

Is there any simple way of loading / understanding an MP3's contents to display a plot of its amplitudes to the screen using wxWidgets?

I later intend to port to C++/wxWidgets for speed and to avoid having to distribute wxPython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more googling, I think [PyMedia](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pymedia/files/pymedia/) might well be a good place to start at least as far as a Python implementation goes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Snack](http://www.speech.kth.se/snack/) could be a good start. I've not used it.

**edit**: It's Tk based, but perhaps there are parts or ideas to be taken.